# What is the difference between もう少しで and ほとんど?

Tags: grammar, usage, nuances

Consider these sentences:

1. (×ほとんど/○**もう少しで**) いうのを忘れるところでした。
2. プールの中の水は、(○**ほとんど**/○**もう少しで**) 満杯である。
3. 宿題は、(○**ほとんど**/×もう少しで) 終わった。
4. (×ほとんど/○**もう少しで**) あなたのお家に着きます。

In some cases it is ok to use もう少しで but in others it is not. The same goes for ほとんど. Sometimes both can be used.

I have heard explanations like ほとんど is mainly used for "possibilities" and are used for 1-D things like time, distance or level and things that have a "span". And もう少しで is used for possibilities. But I have no idea what this means at all.

Can someone explain the grammar behind this and why sometimes they are interchangeable and sometimes they are not?

Comment: It's a typical error to render "I almost killed" to ほとんど殺した, which means "I killed almost everyone".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

English "almost X" can describe two different kinds of situations:

1. mostly X but not completely X

   > - It's almost perfect (but is still imperfect).
   > - I almost forgot it (my memory about it is already vague).
2. X was likely to happen, but it never happened

   > - I almost died (but I didn't die).
   > - I almost forgot it (but I perfectly recalled it before a problem arose).

Now...

- ほとんど is used *only* in Situation 1.

  > - ほとんど完璧です。 It's almost perfect.
  > - 彼はほとんど死んでいるようなものだ。 He's half dead.
  > - 三角関数はほとんど忘れました。 I almost forgot about trigonometric functions.
- もう少しで is typically used in Situation 2. The pattern to memorize is `もう少しで + ～するところだ`, `もう少しで + ～しそうになる`. You can also use 危うく. See [your own previous question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56839/5010) and [Learn JLPT N2 Grammar: ところだった (tokoro datta)](http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n2-grammar-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%93%E3%82%8D%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F-tokoro-datta/)

  > - もう少しで死ぬところだった。 I almost died.
  > - おっと、もう少しで忘れるところでした。 Oops, I almost forgot.
- もう少しで can be (usually) used in Situation 1, too. Still, もう少しでX basically means X has not happened yet or X did not happen. Try thinking this phrase as "with a little more time/effort/resource/luck/misfortune/etc, ..." and see if it fits the context.

  > - もう少しで満杯です。 With a little more water, it will be full.
  > - もう少しで終わります。 With a little more time, it will be done.
  > - もう少しで勝てた。 With a little more luck/effort, we could win. (i.e., we lost)
  > - 彼はもう少しで死ぬ。 He will die soon / with a little more damage.
  > - ×もう少しで終わった。 (weird)

Typically, もう少しで is closer to "soon" rather than "almost". Compare:

> - もう少しで春です。 Spring will come soon (but it has not come yet).
> - もうほとんど春です。 It's already almost spring (it's warm).

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer and I appreciate the examples very much! I understand why もう少しで終わった。would be weird. But would for example 宿題は、もう少し終わっていたwork? To say "I almost finished my homework (I didn't)." This is like the example you used もう少しで勝てた。

Comment: @shade549 Yes, 宿題はもう少しで終わっていた sounds to me like you were about to finish the homework but never actually finished it for some reason. 宿題はほとんど終わっていた is simply "was almost done."

Answer (score 1):

**もう少しで** implies that the action or result of a certain verb is not completed/finished but its completion comes soon, so it goes with the present tense or the future tense like もう少しで終わる or もう少しで終わるでしょう/終わるだろう but doesn't go with the past tense like もう少しで終わった.
If you want to say something in the past tense using もう少しで, you can make it by constructing a sentence in the past tense which encompasses the present tense like もう少しで終わるところだった, which means 実際{じっさい}にはその時までには終わらなかった *Actually it was not completed/finished before the designated time*.

On the other hand **ほとんど** implies that the action or result of a certain verb is **mostly** completed/finished, so it goes with the past tense or verbs that express the state of things like (宿題｛しゅくだい｝は)ほとんど終わった, (宿題は)ほとんど終わる or (宿題は)ほとんど終わるでしょう/終わるだろう.